# Can the frequency of the SPI sck on an mbed be adjusted?

Tags: spi, frequency, mbed, clock

I'm trying to control a serial dataflash memory through the SPI interface of an mbed. SCK from the mbed is connected to CLK of the dataflash memory. I'm not sure, but I'm starting to suspect that this needs to be running at a certain frequency. Can the frequency be adjusted?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change the frequency of the clock,
http://mbed.org/projects/libraries/api/mbed/trunk/SPI#SPI.frequency

> frequency
>
> void frequency( int     hz   =  1000000 )
>
> Set the spi bus clock frequency
>   Variables
>   hz  SCLK frequency in hz (default = 1MHz)